# How many states can show a mouse cursor on Linux?

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, application, icons

Usually when using Windows people have several mouse states and each state have an icon and means something different. I'm testing a Mint 19 and I'm not able to see the states "application starting" or "working in background". Is there any way to solve this? Maybe using a different mouse icon set?

Answer (score 0):

The available mouse cursors depend on the toolkit being used; plain X [knows at least 77 different cursors](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/appendix/b/), Gdk [knows at least 34](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Cursors.html#gdk-cursor-new-from-name).

The cursor being used is controlled by each application, for any window or widget it displays on the screen. There isn’t a global cursor, so there is no state for “application starting”; applications can choose to display a “busy” cursor, but they have to take care of that themselves.

Comment: So if I've understood correctly, every app should tell what mouse icon cursor to use on every event... But hey, in [GDK3](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Cursors.html#gdk-cursor-new-from-name) I've found the cursor state known as "progress", that would be equivalent to "app_starting" or "working_background"... So a mouse cursor depends on 2 things, first the state the app wants to show and second, if the icon for that state is available in the icon set, right?